# Java swing: which component handles the mouse event to resize a JFrame or JDialog

Tags: java, swing, resize, mouselistener, jdialog

Java 8 on windows 10.
I have a resizable JDialog.
I have tried the following code to see if I can capture the mousePressed & mouseReleased event when the mouse cursor changes shape at the edge of the JDialog and ready to be pressed and dragged to resize the JDialog,

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
                        MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent)event;
                        System.out.println("mouse event captured");
                    }
                },  AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

But the above code could not capture any mouse event during the procedure of pressing/dragging/releasing the mouse to reside the JDialog. It can capture all mouse events if the mouse pointer is inside the boundary of the JDialog, though.

How can I capture the mousePressed/mouseDragged/mouseReleased event during the procedure of resizing the JDialog by using the mouse?

Comment: *How can I capture the mousePressed/mouseDragged/mouseReleased event during the procedure of resizing the JDialog by using the mouse?* - you can't. JFrame and JDialog use OS widgets, so access to the title bar and borders is not available in Swing. What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think you need access to the MouseEvents?

Comment: The actual content JPanel is added to a JScrollPanel, the JScrollPanel is then added to the rootPane of the JDialog. The size of the content JPanel may be changed by showing/hiding components via code, or by resizing the JDialog by pressing and dragging the mouse. If the size change is caused by the code, I want to resize the JDialog to get ride of the scrollbars if the screen size is big enough.

Comment: The scrollbars will appear/disappear automatically as components are added/removed from the panel. The scrollbar is also controlled automatically as the dialog size is changed if you use the appropriate layout managers. So the issue is with your code.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can make the UI a little bit smarter for two cases. One is change font and font size, the second is change display language, all in GUI, not in system. Since the only component in the rootPane is a JScrollPanel, the scrollbar will hide or show as the actual content panel size change. What I want to achieve is, if the user never manually resize the JDialog by dragging the mouse, I want to adjust the JDialog size in code so that the scrollbar won't show up if the screen size is big enough; otherwise the JDialog size won't be adjusted and let the scrollbar stay.

Comment: A component will automatically adjust its preferred size if the Font is changed and therefore the scrollbars will automatically adjust. That is adjustments will be make automatically when you use layout managers. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to execute code when the JFrame/JDialog is resized, then just JFrame/JDialog.addComponentListener method. When the window is resizing, the componentResized is called.

If you want to distinguish between change size with code or change size by dragging just use a boolean:

```
resizingByCode = true;
resize();
resizingByCode = false;
```

And in componentResized check this boolean.